# Emit to all sockets on regular interval in socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am wondering how I can send out a message to sockets on an interval, currently I am doing:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('message', variable);
}, 100);

...
```

Each user then has an interval emitting messages every 100ms. Is there a better way of doing this?

I am also confused about how emit works: I was under the impression it sent the message to all sockets, but if I only start this interval for the first socket that connects and not the following sockets only the first socket receives the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `io.emit` to emit to all connected sockets. You can still do this in an interval as well.

```
// Only needed if you have to do something with a specific socket
io.on('connection', handleSocket);

setInterval(() => {
    io.emit('message', variable);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose () => is coffeescript for a function definition?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

just don`t forget to call clearInterval() finction when the socket connection is close.